# The bottom rectangle gets deleted instead of the top-most

Tags: python, loops, pygame

I'm showing 25 rectangles (objects of My_rect) randomly  on the screen.

```
rects = []
for i in range(25):
    rects.insert(0, My_rect(canvas))
```

My goal is to remove them as I click on them.

This is how I'm handling clicks:

```
if ev.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP and ev.button == 1:
    click_x, click_y = ev.pos

    for cur_rect in rects:
        if cur_rect.contains_point(click_x, click_y):
            rects.remove(cur_rect)
            break
```

The contains_point function is defined like this:

```
def contains_point(self, point_x, point_y):
    rect = Rect(self.x, self.y, self.width, self.width)
    return rect.collidepoint(point_x, point_y)
```

When I click on a separately-positioned rectangle, it gets deleted, as it should be. However, when I click on a rectangle that overlaps another one beneath it, the bottom-most rectangle disappears, which is contrary to my goal.
To me, the strangest thing is that I specifically added rectangles to rects using insert(0, ...) and not append() in order to prevent that effect.

What haven't I taken into consideration?

Comment: Aren't your rectangles drawn in the order of your list (so, the first ones at the bottom)?

Comment: They shouldn't be. As far as I understand insert(0, ...), it puts newer objects to the beginning, while the older ones get upwards on the list. Then, when I draw the objects, I use
[for cur_rect in rects:]
which goes from beginning to end, so from newer to older ones. In theory, at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you explain in your comment, you draw the rectangles in the order they appear in the list, so the first ones are drawn first, and end up at the bottom.

Then, you also test for the click by iterating on the list in the same order, so you test the rectangles at the bottom first.

The way you inserted the rectangles in the list is irrelevant. Just do it using `append` - furthermore, using `insert(0)` is very inefficient for large lists, as all items have to be moved each time you insert one.

Just iterate the list in reverse order when testing for the click:

```
for cur_rect in reversed(rects):
    if cur_rect.contains_point(click_x, click_y):
        rects.remove(cur_rect)
        break
```